# Avoid redeclaring types when consuming values from context provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Fairly new to Typescript and would like to know if there's a way to avoid redeclaring a type when consuming a value from Context.

Simplified example below to explain what I mean:

In the Context file:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const updateName = (name: string) => {
 setName(name);
};

  return (
    <TasksContext.Provider
      value={{
        name,
        updateName
      }}>
      {children}
    </TasksContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then in the component that is consuming the context:

```
import TasksContext from '../../context/TasksContext';

const {
    updateName
  } = useContext(TasksContext);

<Switch
   onValueChange={() => {
     updateName(57); //doesn't error as updateName is any
   }}
 />
```

I know I can provide the type safety again by doing the following in the component that is consuming the context by doing the following:

```
 const {
    updateName
  } = useContext<updateName: (string) => {}>(TasksContext);
```

But that seems a bit overkill as shouldn't Typescript be able to infer that it's function that requires an argument that is a string from the Context provider? If I add another parameter to the function in the Context file, I've then got to find where it's being called across the app and edit the types again.

Thank you.

Comment: When you call `createConext()`, are you providing a type there?

Comment: No - `const TasksContext = React.createContext();`

Comment: I think what you're after is providing a type there: `React.createContext<TasksContextType | undefined>();` (you'll have to check for undefined as well since `useContext(TasksContext)` can return undefinend if it's not used within your `TasksProvider`.

Comment: I see! Yes this looks like it will sort my issue out (throws up another issue regarding undefined, but it's moved me along. Many thanks indeed. Will return if I'm unable to resolve the new issue!

Comment: No worries, I added an answer that covers how you might handle the undefined/null issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a type parameter when you create your context:

```
type TasksContextType = {
  name: string; 
  updateName: (name: string) => void;
};
const TasksContext = React.createContext<TasksContextType | null>(null);
```

This will type the `value` prop to be of the `TasksContextType` or `null` if `useContext(TasksContext)` is used outside of the `TasksContext.Provider`. This can make the call to `useContext()` a bit superfluous:

```
const { updateName } = useContext(TasksContext) ?? {}; // <-- annoying default each time you use `TasksContext`
// What to do here if updateName is null?
```

A common approach is to put the `useContext()` call into its own hook that handles the `null` by throwing an error, allowing your custom hook to return a type of `TasksContextType`:

```
export const useTasks = () => {
  const tasksCtx = useContext(TasksContext);
  if (tasksCtx === null) {
    throw new Error("Invalid hook call, useTasks must be called within a TasksProvider");
  }
  return tasksCtx;
}
```

In your component, you'd use this like so:

```
const { updateName } = useTasks();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your missing type definitions for `name` and `updateName` is - like you mentioned in your comment - that you don't define the type while you creating your context.

In your current implementation you create a context without any types or default values. So typescript does not know how your context looks like.

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

// your current implementation
const context = createContext()
```

If you want to get the correct typing when you use your `TaskContext` with `useContext(TaskContext)` you have to provide either default values for implicit typing or use explicitly a type definition to define the context.

My preferred way to tackle this problem is to provide default values while creating the context. With this approach you will get your type definition when you use your `TaskContext` and you don't have to deal with the problem, that your `TaskContext` could be null or whatever in some cases.

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

// context gets implicit type from the provided default values
const context = createContext({ name: '', updateName: (name: string) => {} })
```

Thanks to @Nick Parsons there is a good example for creating a context by using an explicit type.